# C# поиск слова в тексте

Tags: c#, строки, поиск

Допустим текст я считываю из файла в строку - это легко. Далее я могу искать методами `Contains()` или `IndexOf()` и даже могу игнорировать регистр что хорошо, но очень плохо то что слова ищутся не целиком! Допустим если поисковое слово входит в какое либо другое большое слово, то по-прежнему найдется. Как мне искать только по отдельным словам?

Comment: Split строки на отдельные слова и поиск на полное совпадение по массиву слов, или используйте регулярное выражение

Comment: Да кажется нашел решение, можно в регулярках использовать \b вот так: (\bслово\b) вроде работает. еще с табами надо проверить)

Comment: Вы можете сами написать подробный ответ, когда найдёте решение которое вас устраивает и принять лучший, если будут другие ответы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самый простой способ поиска слова целиком - это использовать регулярное выражением, например, воспользовавшись функцией [Regex.IsMatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s19z3syh.aspx).
Регулярное выражение должно содержать само слово, которое мы ищем, добавив в начало и конец символ [\b](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) - символ для ограничения границы слова

```
bool result = Regex.IsMatch(text, "\\bслово\\b");
```

Специальный символ `\b` срабатывает в следующих случаях:

- Перед первым символом в строке, если первый символ является символом
  слова.
- После последнего символа в строке, если последний символ
  является символом слова.
- Между двумя символами в строке, где первый из
  них - символ слова, а другой не символ слова(например, пробел).

*Символ слова* - это символы регулярного выражения [\w](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html).